# Is Saika also based on some old folklore?

Tags: durarara

In Ikebukuro there are two living urban legend, The "Black Rider" and The "Slasher".

[image]

The "Black Rider" Celty Sturluson is a [dullahan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dullahan). And The "Slasher" Saika (currently in the possession of Sonohara Anri) is an entity that manifests itself as a cursed Japanese sword.

Celty is based on Irish mythological figure, so is Saika also based on some old folklore?

Comment: Why would she be? You yourself just stated that *she's* a cursed Japanese sword.

Comment: well, there are [Muramasa swords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muramasa), but I don't know if this legend was  an inspiration for Saika.

Comment: Saika is inspired by the often used trope of souls within swords but she is not really related to any known folklore as far as we know.

Answer (score 3):

In Japan folklore, there is no such thing as a cursed blade which turns people into slaves or zombies or whatever Saika turns people into.

Many of the most known cursed blades are Muramasa's, however they are rather famous for being able to cut through armor while regular blade were used on weak spots (not even close to saika's abilities) or to make their owner mad like they were controlling them (**closer but not that much**).

Sources :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muramasa
http://www.ancient-origins.net/artifacts-other-artifacts/curse-samurai-muramasa-blades-002878

*I recommand reading the second one which is really interesting.*

Hope that helps.